# Save row values in lists depending on values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently looking for a possibility to write a function for the following problem. I have a dataset with the following form: Beginning with the second column, the column name are changing over time. I would like to get the values of the first (fixed) column as a list, where the value of the column is 'a' for each of the following columns (for the first column this would be Test_1, Test_3 and so on).

| Fixed Column | First variable column | Second variable column | Third variable column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test_1 | a | 0 | a |
| Test_2 | 0 | a | a |
| Test_3 | a | 0 | 0 |

A function would be perfect that would allow me to create lists of all the rows values of the first column where the value is 'a' for each of the following columns.

Do you have an idea for a function that looks at the columns separately and saves the lists of values from the first column dynamically?

Comment: Pls explain the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function as follows:

```
# pass a column label of variable column to get the list of values from Fixed Column
def get_list(col):              
    return df.loc[df[col] == 'a', 'Fixed Column'].to_list()
```

Then, for example, you can iterate over the variable columns to get the lists as follows:

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    print(get_list(col))
```

Output:

```
['Test_1', 'Test_3']
['Test_2']
['Test_1', 'Test_2']
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the output (and the solution of course) I was looking for.

Comment: Maybe a question regarding a little modification: In case I want to have the output in form of multiple dataframes with the names of the corresponding columns from the origin dataframe as the column names (still not sure which way of data processing will turn out to be appropriate) how should I modify the first generic function?

Desired output(s):

Dataframe 1:
| First variable column |
| -------- |
| Test_1   |
| Test_3   |

Dataframe 2:
| Second variable column |
| -------- |
| Test_2   |

And so on...

Comment: @TOm_99  I'm afraid I don't have enough equipment to support your revised question since I only have a mobile phone on hand now.  Would you mind posting a new question to let other members also look at your new question. Most probably someone else could help.